# What is the order of allocation of containers in HADOOP YARN within a single application using capacity-scheduler?

Tags: java, hadoop, scheduling, hadoop-yarn, job-scheduling

I have a single YARN application running on a **cluster of 1 master node(Resourcemanager) and 3 slave nodes (Nodemanagers) - total memory= 24GB, total vcores= 12**. I am using **Hadoop 2.4.1** and scheduler is **Capacity-Scheduler** with **DominantResourceCalculator**. This application submits 10 container requests to ResourceManager through the asynchronous AMRM client ( **AMRMClientAsync**). The behavior I observed was that the container request asking for the most resources gets allocated first. For eg. 9 requests are for 2GB containers and 1 request is for a 4 GB container, then the 4GB container gets allocated and here's where it runs into a problem - It just stops there - it doesn't allocate any containers for all the 2 GB requests!

Once a container is allocated my app runs a task on it and once it is finished , app submits a fresh container request for this task (the tasks are of a repeating nature). Then again the RM allocates a 4GB container for this request, completely ignoring all the requests in between. I don't know if it is an issue with the **AMRMClientAsync** class- I haven't tried using the normal AMRMclient yet. Now I have tasks that require 2 GB and tasks that require 4 GB memory. Because of this problem it is only running the 4 GB task again and again.

If all the container requests are identical in terms of resources, then this problem disappears and RM allocates all requested containers.

Couldn't find any documentation/known bugs relating to this. I've hit a brick wall here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found the answer? I am also learning the pros and cons between AMRMClient and AMRMClientAsync?

Comment: @MichaelDinh It's a bug - See the [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-314). Resource Requests of different size and same priority are not supported . I quote from the Jiira - "The issue is that AppSchedulingInfo loses that information by storing ResourceRequest only by priority and location instead of priority, location and size."